# Ruby: Generate a utf-8 character from code point as string

Tags: ruby, utf-8

I need to write all utf-8 characters in file. I have all codes as string "5363" or "328E", but I can't add it to \u, to make structure, like "\u5363". Help me please.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(this will work if you have ruby 1.9 or newer)

```
#irb -E utf-8
irb(main):032:0> s=""
=> ""
irb(main):033:0> i=0x328e
=> 12942
irb(main):034:0> s<<i
=> "㊎"
irb(main):036:0> s<<0x5363
=> "㊎卣"
```

for your case:

```
my_char_codes = ["5363","328E"]
s = ""
my_char_codes.each{ |c| s << c.to_i(16) }

# now s contains "㊎卣"
```

Comment: "RangeError: 12942 out of char range". Ruby Console write it, when i try your code. I use Ruy 1.9.2

Comment: try to invoke ruby console as `irb -E utf-8`

Comment: Thx, it works, but how use the same "irb -E utf-8" in my code? I use RubyMine.

Comment: add a `#encoding: utf-8` line at beginning of your code file(s)